# Using grep to have only interface name and MAC address over MacOs ifconfig

Tags: bash, macos, mac-address, ifconfig

I'm using MacOS and to administrate it want to get only by using grep a list with

interfacename and macaddress

```
lo0 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 
gif0 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 
stf0 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 
en0 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 
en5 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 
en1 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 
en2 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 
en3 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 
en4 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 
utun0 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

I tried ad I tried some commands i wrote ut the best that i can do is:

```
ifconfig | echo `grep -oE '^[a-zA-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4}'`

output:

lo0 gif0 stf0 en0 en5 en1 en2 en3 en4 utun0
```

someone more prepared the me?

Comment: `cut` is an appropriate tool for that job. Look what it does and you'll be able to solve it easily.

Comment: @Quasímodo "cut is an appropriate tool for that job. Look what it does and you'll be able to solve it easily". I look it but i don't kwno it very well and I want to resolve it with grep.

Comment: @Cyrus "Please take a look at: What should I do when someone answers my question?" DONE. Thank U

Comment: Some users going off topic in comments. Please read the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Perl script to read the output of `ifconfig` will work. We define the instance name (`$inst`) as the characters that begin a line and end with a colon and one or more whitespaces. A match meeting this criteria is saved and the read loop continues. When a line begins with one or more whitespaces and the token `ether` is encountered, we print the instance name and the line just read.

```
ifconfig|perl -ne 'if (m/^(.+):\s+/) {$inst=$1};if (m{^\s+ether}) {print $inst,$_}'
en0     ether 34:15:9e:23:7b:78 
en1     ether 7c:6d:62:73:ff:4e 
p2p0    ether 0e:6d:62:73:ff:4e
```

If a `grep`-only parsing is insisted upon, this will yield a crude extraction which can then be further massaged:

```
ifconfig|grep -Eo '^[0-9a-z]+:|ether.+'|grep -B1 -Eo 'ether.+'|grep -v -- "--"|paste - -

en0:    ether 34:15:9e:23:7b:78 
en1:    ether 7c:6d:62:73:ff:4e 
p2p0:   ether 0e:6d:62:73:ff:4e
```

Comment: Your solutions works so perfectly that i'm tempted to put you the V (and i do that if none knows a different way) but i asked for grep and not 4 perl, so I looking forward a little bit. The variable $inst works, and prints interfaces of ifconfig in loop continues without whitespaces. I saved it on my file. It's just what i wanted, but not with perl!! So... your explanation is beautiful like your solution and i read it carefully. You'll probably have your check the same :)

Comment: You're the king. I want to disturb you just an other time. Can you give me the same output of the other without going next line (and without --)?! PLEEEEEEEEEEEZ

Comment: "Please READ: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers" -> I've read your link. I made you mad. But you make perfectly what I asked. Love you. I accept your solution because It's the top. The only one detail it's that spaces are not aligned from a line to an other. But I'ts a detail. FergusonJr you're the bist. Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This may get you a little closer:

```
grep -o '\b[0-9a-z:]*[0-9]\b'
```

But the output has new lines in it:

```
lo0
00:00:00:00:00:00
gif0
00:00:00:00:00:00
stf0
00:00:00:00:00:00
en0
00:00:00:00:00:00
en5
00:00:00:00:00:00
en1
00:00:00:00:00:00
en2
00:00:00:00:00:00
en3
00:00:00:00:00:00
en4
00:00:00:00:00:00
utun0
00:00:00:00:00:00
```

However, if you would permit the use of xargs, you can get a solution that has your interface and mac on the same line:

```
grep -o '\b[0-9a-z:]*[0-9]\b'  | xargs -L2
lo0 00:00:00:00:00:00
gif0 00:00:00:00:00:00
stf0 00:00:00:00:00:00
en0 00:00:00:00:00:00
en5 00:00:00:00:00:00
en1 00:00:00:00:00:00
en2 00:00:00:00:00:00
en3 00:00:00:00:00:00
en4 00:00:00:00:00:00
utun0 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

The grep is looking for a string that contains a number.  Thus, ether is omitting from the matching strings.  Of course, this is not a very general solution.

Of course, if you want to use the shell substitution back tics (or better `$()`):

```
 ifconfig | echo $( grep -o '\b[0-9a-z:]*[0-9]\b'  )
```

Comment: i tried your solutions but no one works like expected. I think you haven't tried it on your terminal. The result it's a mixture of characters that have no sense :). Probably you wrong the regex. I don't know. Thank u the same